# Keychain sharing between two apps

Tags: ios, keychain

Apple has provided Generic Keychain sample which is written in Swift, I want to go ahead with Objective-C.

I have enabled keychain sharing in both the apps and on canOpenUrl I am able to invoke application B from A, now I want to share username and password from app A to app B. App ID is same for both the applications.

I have looked at various tutorials also don't want to use any third party project.
Could not came to know how to pass the parameter from app A to app B.

Comment: Maybe helpful: http://evgenii.com/blog/sharing-keychain-in-ios/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Enable Keychain sharing:**

1. Turn on the Keychain Sharing capability.
2. Select developer team
3. Specify Keychain group name to something meaningful (for example testKeychainG1)
4. Open .entitlements file and replace $(AppIdentifierPrefix) with your APP ID (for example AB123CDE45.testKeychainG1)

**Accessing Keychain (Retrieve shared items):**

```
let itemKey = "Item Key"

let keychainAccessGroupName = "AB123CDE45.testKeychainG1"


let query:[String:Any] = [
    kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword,
    kSecAttrAccount as String: itemKey,
    kSecReturnData as String: kCFBooleanTrue,
    kSecMatchLimit as String: kSecMatchLimitOne,
    kSecAttrAccessGroup as String: keychainAccessGroupName
]

var result: AnyObject?

let resultCodeLoad = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &result) {
    SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, UnsafeMutablePointer($0))
}

if resultCodeLoad == noErr {
    if let result = result as? Data,
        let keyValue = NSString(data: result,
                                encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as? String {

        // Found successfully
        print(keyValue)
    }
} else {
    print("Error: \(resultCodeLoad)")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**step 1:**

Set *URL Schemes* and add the **AppA**'s *URL Scheme* to the **AppB**'s `info.plist` like this:`<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>Aapp_Scheme</string>
    </array>`

**step 2:**

In app A:

```
let url = URL.init(string: "B_Scheme://name=Obama&password=Trump");
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: ["":""], completionHandler: nil);
    }
```

**step 3:**

In app B's **AppDelegate.swift** add the code:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    var name  = "", password = "";
    let param = url.absoluteString.replacingOccurrences(of: "B_Scheme://", with: "");
    let paramArray = param.components(separatedBy: "&");
    for temp in paramArray {
        if (temp.range(of: "name=") != nil){
            name = temp.replacingOccurrences(of: "name=", with: "");
        }
        else if (temp.range(of: "password=") != nil){
            password = temp.replacingOccurrences(of: "password=", with: "");
        }
    }
    if name == "Obama" && password == "Trump" {
        print("get param success!");
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, it is working but not secure way to pass sensitive info.

Comment: And you can get the messages of the other app's?